# Spark structured streaming multi-actions share same checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

imagine I have one stream from structured streaming.

```
val sourceDF = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", revBrokers)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      ...
      as[(String, String)]
```

and I want to count the number of Rows when first field is not empty String at the same time write this into hdfs.

pseudo code:

```
sourceDF.filter(_.1 != "").count.writeStream.option("checkpointPath", <cp-1>).format("console").start()
sourceDF.writeStream.option("checkpointPath", <cp-2>).start(<descDir>)
```

but now those 2 streams are out of sync, because they run independently.
however, what I truly want is to count the non-empty rows and print out the number at the same time, saving the stream to hdfs so I know how many rows I've saved have non-empty first field.

anyone has any ideas how to achieve this? I know spark streaming is not designed for this(side effect processing), but sometimes multi-actions would be very useful(spark streaming can do this, since it's using micro-batches).

Comment: with spark-2.4.0, it's kinda possible to workaround this. but not fully. Spark-2.4.0 supports `foreachBatch((data: T, batchID: Long)): Unit`. but it would be really good to support 'side-effect'ish action on the stream, like SparkStreaming intermediate microRDD. I know spark guys won't like this, because this makes flow not pure anymore, but in some cases, like the one I stated above, it would be super helpful.

Comment: hello, does checkpointing work with a foreachBatch sink.

Comment: It does. Since for each batch just gives you normal data frame to operate.